# Closing link in a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need help with closing a div tag that has been expanded using jquery when a "read more" link has been clicked.

I can get one to work but not the rest.

I have attached a fiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/R9LvG/

This is the first time i have ever used jquery and i am very new to it so please bear with me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme").click(function () {
        $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme2").click(function () {
        $(".content2").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme3").click(function () {
        $(".content3").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme4").click(function () {
        $(".content4").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme5").click(function () {
        $(".content5").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".clickme").click(function () {
    $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
 });
$(".clickme2").click(function () {
    $(".content2").slideToggle("slow")
});
$(".clickme3").click(function () {
    $(".content3").slideToggle("slow")
})
$(".clickme4").click(function () {
    $(".content4").slideToggle("slow")
});
$(".clickme5").click(function () {
    $(".content5").slideToggle("slow")
});
$(".close").click(function () {
    $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
});

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9LvG/2/)

Also:

remove the '#' href to prevent it from jumping to the top of the page whenever it is clicked

```
<a class="clickme"><u><b>Read more</b></u></a>
```

To your clickme css class:

```
.clickme{cursor:poniter}
```

and then add a hover event:

```
.clickme:hover{color:#F00}
```

Comment: Hi, i have removed the href to to stop it jumping to the top of the page when its clicked, but now when i hover over the link the cursor doesnt change to the little hand it just stays as the text cursor if you know what i mean? @Dylan de St Pern

Comment: @Danniellexbx Let me know if thats what you wanted.

Comment: yes, but i added cursor:hand; after cursor:pointer; to make it into the gloved hand. Thanks

Comment: @Danniellexbx No prob, if this answer helped you, you could tick it.

Comment: I used part of your answer but part of other peoples answer too, so i dont know which one to tick lol

Comment: Which ever one you want to :)

Answer (score 1):

As all those part of code are crappy, I would use :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[class^="clickme"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
 });
```

Simpler, cleaner.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You close it 2 times which means it opens up again

Remove this at the end

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".close").click(function () {
    $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use dom ready functions more times in a single page.
>
> Use Multiselector for click functions
>
> For examples

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#selector1,#selector2, ... #selector-n").click(function () {
    $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use only one

```
$(document).ready(function () { 


$(".clickme2, .clickme3, .clickme4, .clickme5").click(function () {
    $(this).slideToggle("slow");


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any problem in you code.
You modify the anchor tab by removing the **href=""** element, this will prevent moving the page to top each time you click on **Read more**.

```
<a class="clickme2" ><u><b>Read more</b></u></a>
```

And include the jQuery script in you page by copyng the below content in your page,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

And you can update the script for expanding and compressing as below since you are dealing with different divs with different classes,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme").click(function () {
        $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
    });

    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
    });
    $(".clickme2").click(function () {
        $(".content2").slideToggle("slow")
    });

    $(".clickme3").click(function () {
        $(".content3").slideToggle("slow")
    });

    $(".clickme4").click(function () {
        $(".content4").slideToggle("slow")
    });

    $(".clickme5").click(function () {
        $(".content5").slideToggle("slow")
    });

    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".content").slideToggle("slow")
    });
})
</script>
```